# is firing multiple rpc calls equivalent to multi-threading?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, browser, asynchronous

even though the browser javascript engine is single threaded, you can rapid fire a number of rpc's using async callbacks. it appears that they are all processing concurrently. naturally, I expect upon their return, the async callback are merged into a single thread.

However, if the rpcs are all running concurrently, that would be considered multi-threading, would it not? Any one knows how that would be possible in a single thread javascript engine?

Comment: _"if the rpcs are all running concurrently, that would be considered multi-threading, would it not?"_ No, it would not. Concurrency is not synonymous with multithreading, and concurrency is not parallelism.

Comment: Further (to what @MattBall has said), JavaScript requires that the event handlers for the AJAX calls be executed serially, and that (apart from some side-cases with `onfocus/onblur`) the event handlers be uninterrupted event when they themselves cause new events to be raised -- which means that the serialisation of the handler can go very deep into the function call graph; even across event handlers. JavaScript in a browser could described as "the opposite of concurrent" :-)